# SQL special characters escaping from input

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

In my database I have some file paths, at some point I need to update part of the path. How to deal with special characters for ex. in `\ruba` to `\rubla` when updating data.

`\r` is special char

`\rubla` comes from C# input param to SQL query

SQL:

```
update table
set Location = CONCAT('gabiluca.at.gmail.com\folder', 
                       substring(Location, length('gabiluca.at.gmail.com\director') + 1))
where Location like 'gabiluca.at.gmail.com\\\\folder%'
```

`\\\\`translates to `\`

Simple case:

In a mysql table you have a windows relative path stored in a column named Location.

```
Id  Name    Location
38  MuseScore 3.lnk gabiluca.at.gmail.com
39  redenumit   gabiluca.at.gmail.com
40  interior    gabiluca.at.gmail.com\redenumit
41  FileZilla Client.lnk    gabiluca.at.gmail.com\redenumit
42  MuseScore 3.lnk gabiluca.at.gmail.com\redenumit\interior
```

Now try to update: 'redenumit' in mysql with an update statement on all records. Dose it work ? Keep the prefix. Think of it like when you rename the folder 'redenumit' to 'changed' for example.

I'm not even able to query like this (this is the problem):

```
select * 
from MediaResource
where Location like 'gabiluca.at.gmail.com\redenumit%'
```

Comment: Are you looking for [verbatim string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)?

Comment: can you please update what you are trying to do in your query? eg., value 'a' to value 'b'

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes but for mysql

Comment: @sabharikarthik i updated my question. If a inner folder is renamed I need to update the relative paths in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this command:

SET sql_mode = NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES;

and reset:

SET sql_mode = '';

whenever the processing is done?

Comment: SET sql_mode=NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES;
select * 
from MediaResource
where Location like 'gabiluca.at.gmail.com\redenumit%'

NOT WORKING ..

Comment: No :( it did not

Comment: No real problem on update but more on where clause for update or select

Comment: Lets continue this discussion here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191603/room-for-sabhari-karthik-and-gabriel-luca

Comment: It turns out that this is the way to go .. I had a small error that was forcing not results in the query set

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :).